# AWS S3 monitor folder level metrics

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to monitor S3 folder level metrics, trying to get a comparison between two folders.
`s3://logs-bucket/error/2019/01/`

`s3://logs-bucket/info/2019/01/`

I spent an hour playing around with CloudWatch metrics but still have no idea how to do it. I am not trying to do anything fancy, just trying to graph `NumberOfObjects` and `BucketSizeBytes` between 2 folders. Is sub-level metrics a paid feature?

Comment: What do you mean by "sub-level metrics"? There is no such concept as a "folder" in Amazon S3. The full path of the object is part of the filename (Key) of the object. The two metrics you mention operate at the Bucket-level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudWatch provides only bucket level metrics by default. But you can define additional metrics via filters (S3 bucket->Management->Metrics->Filters). Define new metric filter per each prefix (`/error/2019/01/,/info/2019/01/`). Then you can use `FilterId` as a dimension in the CloudWatch S3 query.

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

---

Update: @Tartaglia is right, filters are only for request metrics => you can't get `NumberOfObjects and`BucketSizeBytes`with`FilterId` dimension. So you can't use default CloudWatch functionality for your monitoring. You can script/code it and push requested metrics as a custom metrica to the CloudWatch.

Comment: I think this will only give you request metrics (number of requests, latency, error count ...) but not the number of objects and size.

Comment: That is not a simple feature: you are requesting object level metrics. IMHO standard in this case is to parse all logs from S3 to Elasticsearch/Splunk/..., where you can write any metric/search query.

Comment: for request metrics do i have to enable logging on buckets ?